# How to add new images in Visual Studio 2017 WPF application?

Tags: wpf, image, visual-studio-2017

I am failing to find fast way to add images in Visual Studio 2017 WPF Application.

In previaus versions you could Browse for new images and add to Resources folder.
Are these features removed?

Before:

[image]

Now:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click the project Properties item in Solution Explorer

[image: Properties Item in solution explorer]

Go to the Resources tab

[image: Properties screen showing resources tab]

Click on the small downward triangle next to "Add Resource" and select "Add Existing File". This will open a file selection dialog. Navigate to your images folder and select the images you want to include.

This will create a Resource folder in your project.

[image: Resources in solution explorer]

In solution explorer, select each image in turn and change the Build Action in Properties to Content or Resource.

[image: Resource properties]

Answer (score 1):

[You should simply be able to drag and drop it in,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBAo3.jpg) try rebuilding the project and ensuring the image is set as a resource file. If its still not working try closing down and reopening visual studio.